# link is not working in mobile responsive codeigniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter . I make one website in codeigniter there is one button when i click that button then it redirect to next page that's work fine in desktop of PC but when i working on mobile view than the button link is not working.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('news/The_Bandra_Connection');?>" class="btn btn-transparent-gray">Read More</a>
```

here is css

```
.btn.btn-transparent-gray {
  background: transparent;
  color: #808080;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}
.btn.btn-transparent-gray:hover {
  background: #808080;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Please help me to find out the solution how i solve this problem

Comment: Is this mobile view on a mobile or a pc? If it's a pc, can you provide the compiled html code of the button?

Comment: is in pc..compiled html code means

Comment: is there any one available ..please help me

Comment: Please tell us whether you are able to click link or not? I mean can you atleast touch it? If cant touch then there must be overflow from parent which is blocking that click.

Comment: click is working on pc desktop but not in mobile

Comment: Check this page not jquery code for mobile view or check same in css it can be disable by css or jquery. Or provide you full html.

Comment: @Aziz Paste you entire view page html code and related css, I am sure some parent width is over lapping on anchor tag hence the link is not clickable.

Comment: @Aziz what I mean is what you have posted as your HTML is actually your PHP - so right click on the button that isn't working, and choose inspect element, and you will find that the url in your `href=""` is different to what you put above.

Comment: calv ..by inspect element  which url i get ..its working

Comment: one of the element is being overlapped on your link...So,inspect and find carefully which element is preventing click event

Comment: hii @kunal, the button link is in col-md-8 and i am calling data from database in col-md-4... when i remove the code from col-md-4 then link is working but when i used code in col-md-4 then link is not working

Answer (score 0):

I used clearfix class(`<div class="clearfix">`) of bootstrap in `col-md-8`.Now its working in mobile version also